# I want my discord bot to send a random message to a text room given by user [by channel id or channel name]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so what I am trying to do is when a user write a command such as

```
!setchannel #test or !setchannel 86xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

then the bot will send the random messages to that channel every certain time.

Note that I did the random messages code but I still stuck on creating the !setchannel command.

I am using **discord.js v12.5.3**

---

**index.js** main file

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 30;
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
require('discord-buttons')(client);
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const config = require('./config.json')
const mongo = require('./mongo')
const command = require('./command')
const loadCommands = require('./commands/load-commands')
const commandBase = require('./commands/command-base')
const { permission, permissionError } = require('./commands/command-base')
const cron = require('node-cron')
const zkrList = require('./zkr.json')
const logo =
  'URL HERE'


const db = require(`quick.db`)
let cid;
const { prefix } = config



client.on('ready', async () => {

  await mongo().then((mongoose) => {
    try {
      console.log('Connected to mongo!')
    } finally {
      mongoose.connection.close()
    }
  })
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online`);
  console.log(`${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`);
  console.log(`Server Names:\n[ ${client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.name).join(", \n ")} ]`);





  loadCommands(client)
  cid = db.get(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`)


 
  cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
    const zkrRandom = zkrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * zkrList.length)]
    const zkrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()


      .setDescription(zkrRandom)
      .setAuthor('xx', logo)
      .setColor('#447a88')




    client.channels.cache.get(cid).send(zkrEmbed);
  })

  client.on("message", async message => {




    if (message.author.bot) {
      return
    }
    try {if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') && message.content.startsWith('!s')) return message.reply('you do not have the required permission') } catch (err) {console.log(err)}
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;


    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const cmd = args[0]
    if (cmd === "s") {
      let c_id = args[1]
      if (!c_id) return message.reply("you need to mention the text channel")
      c_id = c_id.replace(/[<#>]/g, '')
      const channelObject = message.guild.channels.cache.get(c_id);

      


      if (client.channels.cache.get(c_id) === client.channels.cache.get(cid)) return message.reply(`we already sending to the mentioned text channel`);
      if (client.channels.cache.get(c_id)) {


       
        await db.set(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`, c_id); //Set in the database
        console.log(db.set(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`))

        message.reply(`sending to ${message.guild.channels.cache.get(c_id)}`);
        cid = db.get(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`)



        const zkrRandom = zkrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * zkrList.length)]
        const zkrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()


          .setDescription(zkrRandom)
          .setAuthor('xx', logo)
          .setColor('#447a88')




        client.channels.cache.get(cid).send(zkrEmbed);



      } else {
        return message.reply("Error")
      }


    }
  })
})




client.login(config.token)
```

**zkr.json** json file

```
[
   "message 1",
   "message 2",
   "message 3"

]
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  What code are you starting with?

Comment: thank you for your respond, no problems I just do not to know how to make a command such I mentioned the details on the question above.

Comment: Show code please....why are we writing this for you?

Comment: I think it was clear enough, anyway I put the code.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews I want to know how to make a command that a user write for example `!set-channel #ChannelName` and after writing that command the code above executed on the mentioned channel by user, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a database to achieve what you're trying to do

An example using [quick.db](https://quickdb.js.org)

```js
const db = require(`quick.db`)
const prefix = "!"
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const cmd = args[0]
    if (cmd === "setchannel") {
        let c_id = args[1]
        if (!c_id) return message.reply("You need to mention a channel/provide id")
        c_id = c_id.replace(/[<#>]/g, '')
        if (client.channels.cache.get(c_id)) {
            await db.set(`_channel_`, c_id) //Set in the database
        } else {
            return message.reply("Not a valid channel")
        }


    }
})
```

Changes to make in your code

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
       let c_id = await db.get(`_channel_`)
        
        cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
        const zkrRandom = zkrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * zkrList.length)]
        const zkrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        
              .setTitle('xx')
              .setDescription(zkrRandom)
              .setFooter("xx")
              .setColor('#447a88')
              .setAuthor('xx#8752')
        
        
            
            client.channels.cache.get(c_id).send(zkrEmbed)
          })
        })
```

The above sample of quick.db is just an example

If you're using repl.it, I recommend you to use [quickreplit](https://quickreplit.js.org)

### Edit

```js
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 30;
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const config = require('./config.json')
const mongo = require('./mongo')
const command = require('./command')
const loadCommands = require('./commands/load-commands')
const commandBase = require('./commands/command-base')
const cron = require('node-cron')
const zkrList = require('./zkr.json')

const db = require(`quick.db`)
const prefix = "!"
let cid;
client.on('ready', async () => {
    await mongo().then((mongoose) => {
      try {
        console.log('Connected to mongo!')
      } finally {
        mongoose.connection.close()
      }
    })
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online`);
    console.log(`${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`);
    console.log(`Server Names:\n[ ${client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.name).join(", \n ")} ]`);    
    
    
    cid = db.get('_channel_')
   
    loadCommands(client)
    //commandBase.listen(client);
   
  })

   
   
  cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
    const zkrRandom = zkrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * zkrList.length)]
    const zkrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 
      .setTitle('xx')
      .setDescription(zkrRandom)
      .setFooter("xx")
      .setColor('#447a88')
      .setAuthor('xx#8752')
 
 
 
     client.channels.cache.get(cid).send(zkrEmbed);
  })
   
  client.on("message", async message => {
     
    console.log(db.get('_channel_'))
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const cmd = args[0]
    if (cmd === "s") {
      let c_id = args[1]
      if (!c_id) return message.reply("You need to mention a channel/provide id")
      c_id = c_id.replace(/[<#>]/g, '')
      if (client.channels.cache.get(c_id)) {
        console.log('old channel')
        console.log(db.get('_channel_'))
        
        await db.set(`_channel_`, c_id); //Set in the database
 
        message.reply(`sending in this channel ${message.guild.channels.cache.get(c_id)}`);
 
       
      } else {
        return message.reply("Not a valid channel")
      }
 
 
    }
  })
```

Comment: it works fine but I when I want to change the channel I must restart the bot, also if I want to make it stop sending messages what should I do, what concept behind it, Thank you

Comment: I fix the restarting problem, but when I changing the channel it keep sending in the old channel and the new channel, I think I did something wrong on my code. this is the code https://pastebin.pl/view/d1b47cef

Comment: Can you log `db.get('_channel_')` or just do this

delete the existing channel from the database by doing `await db.delete('_channel_')`, put that code on the line  above `await db.set('_channel_', c_id)`

Comment: still the same unfortunately it keeps sending in old channel and the new one until I restart the bot - what I did https://pastebin.pl/view/7321c400

Comment: can u send ur ready event, make sure `await db.get(_'channel'_)` is within the event and not outside it

Comment: please check this https://pastebin.pl/view/5138eece in case any mistakes, excuse my confusion, this is the whole code

Comment: I've editted the answer, replace ur code with the editted version and let me know if it works... If it doesn't sorry I can't help beyond this

Comment: still the same problem, anyway thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: can u log c_id and lmk what u get

Comment: well it log the new channel id, and the strange thing is the console don't log the old channel id although it keeps sending to it.

Comment: alright bro, i know the issue now
check the edit now and it should work

Comment: same problem unfortunately, I really appreciate your effort bro, any way I edit the code above and added the json file in case you would like to test it.

Comment: oh yea i found one more mistake, check now

Comment: well it works but the bot need to restart to send to the new channel, otherwise it will keep sending to the old one until I the restart.

Comment: so previously u told it sent in the old and new channel, so put that code in ur message event, that shud fix it

Comment: everything works great, I could not reach this point without your help, thank you so much.

Comment: I hope you still reaching this, anyway this works great but any idea on how I can make this work in multiple servers? I faced this problem. Thank you

Comment: Oh that's easy change the `db.set('_channel_')` to `db.set(\`${message.guild.id}_channel_\`)`

Comment: well I got this error https://pastebin.pl/view/9b738859 , I edited the code with all recent updates, also do I need to put the `${message.guild.id}` in all `db.get('_channel_')`? if yes how can I get the guild id in the ready event since message will not be defined. Thank you

Comment: yes u have to do it for every db.get()
to get the guild id, i think loop through all the guilds of the bot, won't be efficient if ur bot is in many servers though

Comment: I edit the code but I faced the `message is not defined` error for the first `db.get()` line which is obvious it is on ready event and no message defined or declared, I tried to get the guild id with the `client.guilds.cache.map()` since it fetch the all guilds not a specific on so I stuck tbh, I tried to log the `db.set()` line for testing and it only outputs the text channel id without the guild id and that is really makes me more confuse, excuse me confusion any ideas??